Transform JSON to JSON Liquid Template Split using Whitespac
I would like to transform the Incoming JSON field with Full name into First Name and Last Name. We need to split using the Whitespace.  Used both Inline split function and using assign both of them are not splitting the Name its just displayed as Full name with space
[
    {%- for record in content -%}
    {%- assign names = record.Name | split: " " -%}

    {   
        "First Name": "{{ names[0] }}",
        "Last Name": "{{ record.Name | split: " " | last}}",
        "Personal Email": "{{ record['Personal Email'] }}",
        "Project Manager": "{{ record['Project Manager'] }}"
    }{% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %}
    {%- endfor -%}
]


In Logic Apps, Liquid filters must begin with a capital letter e.g., use Split instead of split, etc.
